# QGIS model designer save back into the same geopackage

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler, qgis-expression

I have a model that does some tidying of attributes in vector layers that are stored in a geopackage.
The geopackage to work with is specified with a file path input (@survey_data_package)
Therefore the input layers to work on can be set using the "pre-calculated value" option and an expression like this

```
@survey_data_package || '|layername=TheLayerToWorkOn'
```

When I specify the output layer if I follow the same expression (such as below) it doesn't work - I suspect this is something to do with creating a new layer/table.

```
@survey_data_package || '|layername=TheLayerToSaveOutputTo'
```

If I manually set the geopackage and layer name the string looks like this

```
ogr:dbname='FilePath/Geopackage.gpkg' table="TheLayerToSaveOutputTo" (geom)
```

So I was hoping an expression like the one below would allow me to use a "pre-calculated value" and insert the date etc and standardise the file name. I have tried various possibilities like having the output table name as `"myoutput"` or `myoutput`

```
'ogr:dbname=' || 
@survey_data_package|| 
' table=' || 
'myoutput'  || 
'(geom)'
```

Comment: I think it must be '''myoutput''', cause it must have the double " before and after the name!

Answer (score 2):

This syntax worked

```
'ogr:dbname='
||  @survey_data_package  
|| ' table='
|| 'Survey_' 
||  format_date(now(),'yyyy_MM')
```